# Drop detached partition table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have detached a partition from a partition table and would like to drop the newly created table. I know the SQL server does some asynchronous stuff when I detach the partition and I want to drop the stand-alone detached table with an assurance that the async stuff that the SQL server does is finished. I plan on doing it outside the function where I detach the partition. What is the best way to drop the newly created stand-alone table? How can I be sure the async stuff is done?

Answer (score 0):

Detaching a partition does nothing asynchronous. As soon as `ALTER TABLE ... DETACH PARTITION` returns, the operation is complete.

In fact, all you have to do to remove a partition is to run `DROP TABLE` on the partition. It is that simple.

Comment: This was stated in an IBM documentation regarding dropping partitions, "After ensuring that the asynchronous partition detach task made the target table JUNK available, you can drop the table JUNK, effectively dropping the associated data partition". How do I know the target table (stand-alone table) is available to drop?

Comment: If I drop it outside the function that detaches it, will It be guaranteed to be available to drop?

Comment: All that counts is that the transaction that detaches the partition is committed. If you try to drop the table before that, you will be blocked, but the `DROP TABLE` will automatically resume as soon as the transaction is committed. In other words, nothing can go wrong. Try it out.